# Resolution for android app design

Tags: android, resolution, dpi

I start to design small app for android. But this is my first android app design. And I have a question about devices and displays.
I have read all developer guidelines at http://developer.android.com/, all about DPI and pixels. And still not clear with question.
I want to design in Photoshop CS6 because is the best way for me.

In guidelines i read ***"One approach is to work in the base standard (normal size and MDPI) and scale it up or down for the other buckets. Another approach is to start with the device with the largest screen size, and then scale down and figure out the UI compromises you'll need to make on smaller screens."***

I want to start with the largest screen size so this is XHDPI 320DPI. As an example I want to choose Nexus 4. What resolution (pixels and DPI) do I need to choose for PSD?

I think I need to create PSD with 1280x768px and 320dpi. Is that right? If so, when I need to scale down to 160dpi I have to create new PSD with 160dpi and resize the elements from 320dpi?

Please help me someone I'm confused.

Answer (score 3):

Density and screen size are not the same thing.

XHDPI is the density. 1280x768 is the screen resolution, NOT the screen size. The Nexus 4 has a 4" screen, which is considered "normal" size. If you had a device with an 8" screen and resolution 1280x768, it would be 160dpi, and would be MDPI. However, you can still use the 1280x768 asset you created for the Nexus 4 and the system wouldn't have to scale the image.

Here's how all this relates:
With the Nexus 4's "normal" sized screen, you can display all sorts of UI elements, keeping in mind that they need to be large enough to read, tap, etc. If you launched the same app on an 7" screen, which is considered "large" you might add additional UI elements, since you have so much more real estate. Ok so far?

Now, let's say the 4" screen and the 7" screen have the same resolution (1280x768), they will have a different density. The 4" is XHDPI and the 7" is HDPI (my Nexus 7 reports 213dpi).

If you had a 80x80 image, it would be 1/4" square on the Nexus 4, but 1/3" square on the Nexus 7. The whole UI would look larger and somewhat Fisher-Pricey. Thankfully, Android scales the UI for you, as long as you use "dp" to declare the size of UI elements. You can provide assets in different densities so Android won't have to scale bitmaps too much -- though it still will.

So, if you're developing a phone app, target the normal screen first (and XHDPI if that's your dev device), and provide all the assets in XHDPI. Then create alternate layouts for large screens if you want to make the UI more usable for tablets. Lastly scale your images for other supported resolutions.

You can use PSD, but personally, I prefer vector-graphics as they scale beautifully.

I'm not a PhotoShop user, but since it's raster based, I would start with a higher resolution than you expect using, and scale down. At the very least, I would design for a 1600x2560 Nexus 10, and then scale down from there. In my process, I use CorelDraw (long story), design icons in 1"x1" boxes and then export in the various resolutions.

Comment: Thanks!) I know that I will need to design additional elements for different DPIs. Question is what the best resolution/density to start with when work with app in photoshop? The app has complex UI elements.
The guidelines says "Another approach is to start with the device with the largest screen size, and then scale down and figure out the UI compromises you'll need to make on smaller screens." i like this way. But i don't know what kind of PSD I need to create.

Comment: To work with XHDPI in Photoshop I need to create PSD with 320DPI?
And if I want to work with MDPI I need PSD with 160DPI?

Comment: The DPI you set in Photoshop shouldn't matter. The pixel density is implied when you place the assets (PNG) in the various drawable folders. I.e. your 320dpi PNG goes into drawable-xhdpi.

Comment: OK!) Now I found the answer!)

Comment: Nexus 4: xhdpi = 320ppi (pixels per inch), so 80 px/320 px/in = 1/4 in. Nexus 7: hdpi = 240 ppi, so 80 px/240 px/in = 1/3 in. (corrected)

Answer (score 0):

a little more detail on what you are trying to do would be helpful.  Are you trying to design your icons, or the entire UI, or what?

In android, the UI is designed mainly through xml, and the default styles should be used when possible to stay consistent with the rest of the OS and looking nice.  For many apps, there is no real graphical work to be done accept maybe launcher icons, which there are guides on the developer site for.

If you are trying to design some of your elements like icons, figure out how big they would need to be on the largest screen size, and start from there.  then you can scale them down, but you should not actually be drawing the whole UI or anything.  Take a look at how the graphics are done in some of the android examples, I find them to be extremely useful when trying to figure out how to do things.

Comment: I need to design entire UI with custom design elements. And I need to choose right resolution to start work with. Also I extremely need to see overall UI look when I design.

Comment: well, you cant just draw a ui, it doesn't really work like that.  you make your assets and define how they interact.  the eclipse adt plugin includes a graphic ui design tool, so once you have your images and stuff there isn't too much xml work, but you can't totally just see everything